# Loop array of objects to return correct outcome

Tags: javascript

I have an array with object:

```
 next: [
        {
          max_score: 5,
          outcome: "rest_and_come_back_later"
        },
        {
          max_score: 49,
          outcome: "see_a_doctor"
        },
        {
          outcome: "go_to_emergency_room"
        }
      ]
```

And a variable that holds a patientScore, let us say that the patientScore is 70. If the score is smaller then 5 it should return the outcome rest_and_come_back_later and if it is  then max_score 49 it should return the right outcome. If it higher then 49 it should return the outcome : go_to_emergency_room.

What is the best way to do this in javascript?

Does simple ifelse do the job?, like this:

```
next.forEach((item) => {
    if(patientScore < item.max_score && patientScore >= item.max_score){
        return console.log("max_score: " + item.max_score)
    }else if(patientScore > item.max_score){ return console.log("max_score: " + item.max_score)}})
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: With regards to your `if(patientScore < item.max_score && patientScore >= item.max_score)`: how do you believe that the `patientScore` can be both less-than `item.max_score` *and* greater-than-or-equal-to that same `item.max_score`? Did you mean to use `||` (OR) in place of `&&` (AND)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're returning a value undefined `return console.log(...)` and not only that, but also inside of the handler you're using for the function `Array.prototype.forEach` which it doesn't make sense.
2. An alternative is sorting the array and the just make `<=` comparison in order to find the object with the right `max_score`.

```js
let next = [{      max_score: 5,      outcome: "rest_and_come_back_later"    },    {      max_score: 49,      outcome: "see_a_doctor"    },    {      outcome: "go_to_emergency_room"    }  ],
    // Sort the array to avoid multiple OR conditions.
    array = next.slice().sort((a, b) => {
      if (!('max_score' in a)) return Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
      if (!('max_score' in b)) return Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER;  
      return a.max_score - b.score;
    }),
    // This function finds the specific 'outcome' just comparing the 
    // current index.
    findDesc = (arr, score) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (score <= arr[i].max_score) return arr[i].outcome;
      }
      return arr.slice(-1).pop().outcome;
    }

console.log(findDesc(array, 4));
console.log(findDesc(array, 5));
console.log(findDesc(array, 48));
console.log(findDesc(array, 49));
console.log(findDesc(array, 50));
console.log(findDesc(array, 70));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to define your array with scores in the correct order and then use [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to return `score <= item.max_score`

```js
const list = [
  {
    max_score: 5, outcome: "rest_and_come_back_later"
  },
  {
    max_score: 49, outcome: "see_a_doctor"
  },
  {
    max_score: Infinity, outcome: "go_to_emergency_room"
  }
];

function test(score) {
  // Here it is:
  const item = list.find(i => score <= i.max_score);
  console.log(item.outcome);
}

const testScores = [1, 5, 12, 50, 100];
testScores.forEach(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly, then one approach to this problem might be to define a function `getOutcome()` as shown below.

This method returns the desired outcome, based on input `patientScore` parameter that you pass it:

```js
var object = {
  next : [
    {
      max_score: 5,
      outcome: "rest_and_come_back_later"
    },
    {
      max_score: 49,
      outcome: "see_a_doctor"
    },
    {
      outcome: "go_to_emergency_room"
    }
  ]
};


function getOutcome (score) {

  return object.next.filter(item => {

    if(score < 5) {
      return (item.max_score <= 5)
    }
    else if(score > 49) {
      return (item.max_score >= 49)
    }
    else {
      return (item.max_score > 5 && item.max_score < 49) || (item.max_score === undefined)
    }

  }).map(item => item.outcome)[0]
}

console.log('patientScore = 70', getOutcome(70) );
console.log('patientScore = 3', getOutcome(3) );
console.log('patientScore = 25', getOutcome(25) );
```